# GORM: Create() with different Input and Output Structs

Tags: go-gorm

Is it possible in GORM to give Create() a **Struct A as input** and store the **result in Struct B**?

I haven't found anything suitable in the documentation or on the internet.

The background is as follows:
I let Postgres create the fields id, createdAt and updatedAt - therefore they should not be part of the input Struct A (quasi the DTO/DAO).

However, in the result of Create() these fields are then present - so they should be parsed into Struct B, which contains all the fields of the table.

**Problem if id, createdAt and updatedAt are not explicitly set:**

Go initialises fields of structs that are not explicitly defined with default values, depending on the data type (0, nil etc.).
For the id of type UUIDv4, the value is then `00000000-0000-0000-0000000000`.

Apparently this passed value then overwrites Postgres' `gen_random_uuid()` value for the id column.

Once this works fine, then a duplicyte key error occurs.
createdAt and updatedAt, on the other hand, seem to be generated correctly by Postgres, although I have found Go's default values there as well.

Thank you!

PS: Of course, I could simply create a UUID and give it to the database, but I am basically interested in whether or not my intention can be realised with GORM.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two separate structs, you can use your model to insert/fetch. One way of doing it is to embed [gorm.Model](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Embedded-Struct), which will embed

```
// gorm.Model definition
type Model struct {
  ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

[Embedding](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Embedded-Struct) into User struct.

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Age  int
}
// equals
type User struct {
  ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
  Name string
  Age  int
}
```

Now creating records

```
user := User{Name: "randomname", Age: 18}

result := db.Create(&user) // pass pointer of data to Create

user.ID             // returns inserted data's primary key
user.CreatedAt      // returns inserted data's created at key
user.UpdatedAt      // returns inserted data's updated at key
```

Embedding `gorm.Model` is optional, you can embed it or add the fields to the struct directly or you can create your own struct to embed.

Even if at the time of insert those fields [updatedAt, createdAt] are empty or not part of the input struct, the result will return whatever that is there in database. If the `createdAt` or `updatedAt` are created by postgres and nonEmpty it will be returned.

**update** :- We can use [default values](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values)

```
type HasUuidPkey struct {
        ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
        Name      string
        CreatedAt time.Time
}
```

Playground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/mPTQCUwDRLo)

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is the standard way from the documentation, but it doesn't work in my specific case if you don't set a UUID for id. I have expanded my question above accordingly and explained the problem with the procedure from the documentation.